# Including a file at the root of a built APK

Tags: android, resources, apk

I have a .properties file, which I need at the root-level of a built APK.

The problem is that the file is not added when it begins with an underscore (e.g. _xyz.properties),
but without an underscore it is added at the root.

For example:

[If I place a properties file within my project, called xyz.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubYRa.png)

[and I add that file as a resource by adding the following in build.gradle:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QegdV.png)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/xyzLocation']
    }
}
```

[When I build and inspect the created APK, the xyz.properties file is present at the root.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhCIs.png)

[If I rename the file to _xyz.properties and build an APK again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XJ6y.png)

[_xyz.properties is not present within the APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIv6v.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!! Please add some code that shows your efforts and point out where you got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else encountering this issue, it appears that this is a known issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36911326).

Note, if you're using Eclipse with ADT there's also another issue where the "aapt.ignore.assets" property is ignored (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36961705)